# Setting NODE_ENV differs between Mac and Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-env

I work with a team of 4 and I'm the only Mac user and my peers are using Windows machine.
My team members (Windows users) use the following which was not working on my Mac machine:

```sh
"start": "set \"NODE_ENV=prod\" && node index.js"
```

And when I tried to print `process.env.NODE_ENV` in log it returned `undefined`.

Then after browsing, I used the following on my Mac and it was working fine:

```sh
"start: "export NODE_ENV=prod && node index.js"
```

Now if I commit my **code in repository** they will be **affected**.

**Is there any common solution which can be used to get rid of this platform issue?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [cross-env package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to set environment variables in a cross-platform way.

To install it:

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

To use it:

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=prod node index.js"
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution could be keeping all your environment variables in the respective node environment the code is running in. And for local development, you could add a `.env` file and use a package like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to populate the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can to create a
`"start-mac" :"export NODE_ENV=prod && node index.js"` script only for mac machine.
In package.json you can add custom scripts for windows and mac if its not to update the old scripts.